# Where can I find the concept of Davar ma'amid in the Gemara

Tags: sources-mekorot, kashrut-kosher, talmud-gemara

Where in the Gemara does it talk about the concept of a Davar ma'amid in length regarding kashrut

Answer (score 2):

Gemarah Avodah Zara 29 and 35 . see here for a good resource on the topic: [Iyun Hadaf.](http://dafyomi.co.il/azarah/halachah/az-hl-035.htm)

Comment: Why was I voted down?

Comment: I did not down vote, I don't know why

Comment: @DavidFeigen Probably because your question isn't very well posed. Try 1) using proper grammar 2) explaining any terms which might not be obvious to everyone 3) explaining why you are looking for this information 4) explaining what you have tried so far in order to find it.